# element style declared twice in css but css is not appling the stlye declared at last why is it so?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

css selector specificity is not behaving the expected way.

this is the HTML Code

```
   <nav>
      <p>This is the navigation</p>
      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Challenges</a>
      <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
      <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
   </nav>
```

this is the CSS

this comes first

```
   p {
      font-size: 22px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

after that this comes

```
 nav{
    font-size:18px;
    }
```

as per my understanding in webpage p elememt inside nav element should have 18px but it is having 22px.

Comment: No, style for p element has more weight, so it is 22px

Comment: `p` is a child of `nav`, so its specificity will be higher. The solution depends on your code and what you want. Why did you add `font-size: 22px;` if you don't want it to be applied?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that rarely the order of rules matter in CSS. There are some cases but they are residual and unwanted

Comment: The `nav{ font-size:18px }` targets the `<nav>` tag, not the `<p>` tag. If `p` has its own specific `font-size: 22px`, it won't inherit from the parent (`nav`). Even if you give the parent a class and an id and target it like `nav.specialClass#myId`, the `p` will use its own style, unless you use e.g. `p{ font-size: inherit}`

Comment: Thanks for your timely response now i am totally clear.